# Calling JavaScript from SSRS Report is not working when the report is hosted in Iframe with domain different than that of Parent Page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reporting-services, cross-domain, ssrs-2008

I have an **SSRS** report with link that uses **JavaScript** to open a **subreport** in another window. This SSRS report is hosted inside an **Iframe** in another Website. When the Website and the SSRS report are on the same **domain** (for example http://myserver.com/reportserver/ and http://myserver.com/MyWebsite/) it is working fine. However when the Website and SSRS report server are on **different domains**, it stops Working. It seems that JavaScript calls become disabled, I tried even issuing an Alert from the SSRS report using simple `alert('Hello')` but it doesn't work until i put both the SSRS and Website on the same domain again.

Note: This issue happens only in **IE**, in chrome it is working fine, I am using **SQL reporting services 2008 R2**. The IE versions are **9** and **10**

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved **if** we avoid displaying the report's toolbar element.

Which means you have to add the additional URL parameter, to avoid rendering the toolbar.
Example URL: http:///&rs:Command=Render&**rc:Toolbar=False**

> **Updated (Don't need to omit the Toolbar)**

Add the additional url parameter **rc:LinkTarget=_self** OR **rc:LinkTarget=_blank**.
Because by default SSRS report renders its links with the target attribute as '_top'

Comment: Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: Adding rc:LinkTarget=_self into URL parameters will solve the issue